# Test for month and day but not year

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to test for the month and day, but not the year in batch files, for example a batch file that is different on a specific day but not a specific year?

Comment: I don't understand the issue. Can you add some further detail to your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "skip=10 tokens=3,4,5,6 delims= " %%A in ('@robocopy /l * %tmp% %tmp% /ns /nc /ndl /nfl /np /njh') do ( 
  echo %%B-%%C 
  set "_date=%%B-%%C"
)
if "%_date%" EQU "Nov-02" (
   echo do something
)
```

this will test if date is "Nov-2" and will not rely on time settings format.

Answer (score 0):

show files from `02/11` for all years:

```
for %%a in (*) do echo %%~ta %%~a|findstr /b "02/11/"
```